# Best way to explore census data for Australia?

Tags: r, census

Is there an equivalent to tidycensus for Australia? I am currently trying to explore Australian census data but it seems to be way harder than US census data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind of census data you need, `raustats` might help.
You can get the pacakge right from CRAN with: `install.packages("raustats")`.

Comment: I am particularly looking for income and age, I currently have a shape file of postal codes but I am looking for something which represents the meshblock equivalent. I am surprised how hard it is to use census data from other countries